# Hypothetical Halacha -- Is "Leishayv Basukkah" an interruption of a brocha on Shmini Ateres (if said by mistake)?

Tags: halacha, blessing, hefsek-interruption, shmini-atzeres

This case happened to me over the past Shemini Atzeres, and even though it's over now, I was still curious about the halacha.

I was so used to saying Laysheiv Basukkah the entire Sukkos, so on the first meal of Shemini Atzeres (which is in the Sukkah according to Chabad custom) I started saying the brocho Leishayv Basukkah after Hamotzei, then stopped in the middle and immediately ate the bread, as not to cause further interruption (so I thought).

But I was wondering: would I have had to theoretically make another brocho hamotzei over the bread, since maybe that was considered an interruption, or since my mind wasn't diverted from the food, since I was used to saying the brocho, it wasn't considered an interruption?

Comment: I would assume it is not an interruption (no "hefsek") since the person's mind was not diverted from eating the bread. I will try to find/remember the source.

Comment: @DavidKenner but what if the same thing happened simchas Torah, or the next Shabbos, or any other day of the year? would the same thign be true, or ONLY because it was right after sukkos?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure about this specific case, similar cases are brought up in the rishonim. Specifically, the Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chayim 211:15) says that if one speaks between making kiddush and drinking, he should make another *Hagefen*, but not make kiddush again. The Magen Avraham says there:

> כתוב בפסקי מהרא"י אם קידש על מים וסבר שהוא יין יחזור ויקדש אף על גב דקידוש על היין דרבנן גם במילי דרבנן צריך לחזור עכ"ל ואם היה דעתו לשתות יין יותר א"צ לברך שנית בפה"ג כמ"ש ססי' ר"ט.
>
> It says in the rulings of the Maharai "if one made kiddush on water thinking it was wine, he must repeat kiddush,even though kiddush on wine is derabanan, even by things that're derabanan he must repeat them". And if he had in mind to drink wine, he no longer needs to make another b'racha of hagefen, as it says at the end of siman 209.

However, Rabbi Akiva Eiger (there) disagrees, and says:

> מג"א ס"ק ל"ב: א"צ לברך שנית בפה"ג. לענ"ד כיון דנוסח הקידוש שאמר על הכוס של מים לא הוי קידוש זהו הוי הפסק בין ברכת בפה"ג לשתיית יין אחר
>
> Magen Avraham 32 said: "he need not say Hagefen again". I think that since the language of the kiddush he said on the cup of water is not kiddush, this is a hefsek between the (previous) hagefen and the drinking of other wine.

The [minchas Shlomo (RSZA) 1:18](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15096&st=&pgnum=170) brings this argument and holds like the Magen Avraham, explaining that the problem with a hefsek is distracting oneself from the purpose of the original b'racha. That's why asking for salt - even if there's salt on the table - is not a hefsek, because he thought he needed the salt in order to eat, and he wasn't distracted from eating (even though objectively, the words were unnecessary, since he wasn't distracted, it's still not a hefsek).

However, he goes on to say that this is only true for something that is normal to have before the meal/ mitzva, like accidentally saying the b'racha on fire during havdala of yom Tov, or accidentally counting the wrong day of the Omer. But by other cases, this wouldn't be true. For example, if someone swore to say a certain passuk before eating and only remembered after saying the b'racha, or if one remembered after saying a b'racha that he hadn't prayed yet (and therefore isn't allowed to eat), saying the passuk/ praying would be a hefsek, because "the passuk in and of itself has no relation to the eating..." (My direct translation of his words)

So, in short, RSZA says that if one says something objectively unnecessary, but something that he thought was necessary, as long as what he said is (theoretically) inherently related to the meal, this would not constitute a hefsek, and he wouldn't make another b'racha, so too for the case of an accidental "leisheiv".

---

For further research, see [the Har Tzvi (at the end of siman 194)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=20947&st=%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%A8&_rnd=0.8685785260770209) who might argue with this minchas Shlomo